# Not able to use SSIS package to Sync Data from MySql to AzureSql using ADF-V2

Tags: ssis, azure-data-factory

As we can run SSIS package on ADF-v2.

So I've prepared an SSIS package to Sync records between Mysql and Azure SQL
and getting below error in reports

I'm tried using ODBC and ADO.Net connection but getting same result when trying executing  from SSIS catalog.

I'm able to sync records when i tried executing package from SSDT

Question : Can't we use SSIS in ADF-v2, other than Azure cloud connecters?

Also please suggest if there any steps i'm missing.

Reference links used to implement same
[Link1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-create-azure-ssis-runtime-portal)
 and [Link2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lift-shift/ssis-azure-deploy-run-monitor-tutorial)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might need to install MySQL ADO.NET/ODBC driver on your Azure-SSIS IR via our custom setup interface that's still in Private Preview.  Please fill out our online survey to join: https://www.surveybuilder.com/s/Dg6Bq?source_type=email.

Comment: Is there any static IP given to IR, if so could it be possible that IP need to be allowed to make connection to hosted MySQL, because we've create whitelist to allowed connection to Mysql

Comment: Unfortunately, Azure-SSIS IR doesn't support static IP.  You could try to join it to a VNet/subnet and whitelist the subnet address instead.