# Does Incremental Sync with Azure Data Factory V2 support only Sql Server to Azure SQL

Tags: azure-data-factory

I was trying incremental sync to  design incremental sync data between MySQL and Azure Sql referring [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-multiple-tables-portal#overview) and while designing pipeline for [new watermark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-multiple-tables-portal#create-a-pipeline) found that lookup component only support SQL SERVER.

**Question**

Is there a way to sync incrementally on cloud from hosted Mysql to Azure SQl  using ADF v1/v2?

What other component we can use to select data from Mysql i tried Store Procedure but it support Sql server only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We (ADF team) are actively working on expanding Lookup activity to support more data stores including MySQL.  We will announce when it's ready.  Please stay tuned!

Comment: Thanks for acknowledgement Shirley, Will appreciate if you can please enlighten me on  below thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48826641/not-able-to-use-ssis-package-to-sync-data-from-mysql-to-azuresql-using-adf-v2

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the ADF Control Flow activity "Lookup" does not support MySQL, so the watermark table must exist in an entity that Lookup can communicate with, ao you can create the watermark table and associated sprocs in Azure SQL DB, while pulling the source data from MySQL tables.

Comment: Mark i've created WaterMark Table in Azure SQL only and tried picking data greater than from last value store for table but some how i'm not able to publish same. I'll post same in another thread.