# Not Able to Publish ADF Incremental Package

Tags: azure-data-factory

As Earlier Posted a thread for syncing Data from Premises Mysql  to Azure SQL over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49132994/does-incremental-sync-with-azure-data-factory-v2-support-only-sql-server-to-azur/49142686#49142686) referring this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-multiple-tables-portal#overview), and found that lookup component for watermark detection is only available for SQL Server Only.

So tried a work Around, that while using "Copy" Data Flow task ,will pick data greater than last watermark stored from Mysql.

**Issue**:
Able to validate package successfully but not able to publish same.

**Question** :
In Copy Data Flow Task i'm using below query to get data from MySql greater than watermark available.

Can't we use Query like  below on other relational sources  like Mysql

```
select * from @{item().TABLE_NAME} where @{item().WaterMark_Column} > '@{activity('LookupOldWaterMark').output.firstRow.WatermarkValue}'
```

CopyTask SQL Query Preview
[image]

Validate Successfully
[image]

Error With no  Details
[image]

Debug Successfully
[image]

Error After following steps mentioned by Franky
Azure SQL Linked Service Error (Resolved by re configuring connection /edit credentials in connection tab)
[image]

Source Query got blank (resolved by re-selection source type and rewriting query)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you verify if you have access to create a template deployment in the azure portal?

1) Export the ARM Template: int he top-right of the ADFv2 portal, click on ARM Template -> Export ARM Template, extract the zip file and copy the content of the "arm_template.json" file.

2) Create ARM Template deployment: Go to https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.Template and log in with the same credentials you use in the ADFv2 portal (you can also get to this page going in the Azure portal, click on "Create a resource"  and search for "Template deployment"). Now click on "Build your own template in editor" and paste the ARM template from the previous step in the editor and Save.

3) Deploy template: Click on existing resource group and select the same resource group as the one where your Data Factory is. Fill out the parameters that are missing (for this testing it doesn't really matter if the values are valid); Factory name should already be there. Agree the terms and click purchase.

4) Verify the deployment succeeded. If not let me know the error, it might be an access issue which would explain why your publish fails. (ADF team is working on giving a better error for this issue).

Comment: Thanks. Deployment did succeeded but notify me error while triggering same first Azure SQL Connection, which i reconfigured and second Copy pipeline  Source tab was missing source type(as my source is Mysql) and query to pick incremental value from same source i.e."select * from @{item().TABLE_NAME} where @{item().WaterMark_Column} > '@{activity('LookupOldWaterMarkActivity').output.firstRow.WatermarkValue}' ".  After redoing all stuff i was able to publish from authoring UI now, also login i'm using to configure all this superadmin for my subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Did any of the objects publish into your Data Factory?

Comment: Being a  newbie to this I don't know actually but additionally i debug my pipeline yesterday it too ran successfully. Can you please tell how can i check if any objects is published?

Comment: Open up another browser tab or window and navigate to another authoring UI for your Data Factory. Look to see if the pipeline was published there.

Comment: I checked that and there's nothing published in authoring UI

Comment: Looks like that message is stopping your objects from being published. Can you please report that error msg box to us through the Feedback button on the UI, or through an Azure ticket?